# Reading String and Integer input from text file

Tags: java, input

I have a text file that I'm reading using `BufferedReader`. The text file is of the form, (String, String, Integer). I'm reading each line using the method `inFile.readLine()` and converting to a `String`. I think I'm able to extract the `Integer` part of it using `Integer.parse`, but it's not letting me use `nextLine()`, I think because that's for `Scanner` and not `BufferedReader`.

Here's what I have:

```
 try{
  String nextLine;
  String title = "";
  String department = "";
  int year;

  BufferedReader inFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputName));

  while((nextLine = inFile.readLine())!= null){

    title = nextLine.nextLine();
    department = nextLine.nextLine();
    year = Integer.parseInt(nextLine);
    newList.addCourse(new Course(title, department, year));  
  } 

  inFile.close();
  }
```

Would anyone know how I'm suppose to read the `String` part of my text file?

Comment: "I think because that's for Scanner and not BufferedReader." did you read the javadoc? `String` has no `nextLine()` method..

Comment: I mean you can check for a `String` using Scanner and `nextLine()`. I.e : `String sentence = scanner.nextLine();` And I'm just wondering if there's something similar for BufferedReader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nextLine` is a String, String does not have a `nextLine` method. But why would you want to call nextLine on a String that is already assigned the next line in this condition

```
while((nextLine = inFile.readLine())!= null)
```

If your information always come by group of 3 lines (title, deparment and year) then you could do :

```
while((nextLine = inFile.readLine())!= null){

   title = nextLine;
   department = inFile.readLine();
   year = Integer.parseInt(inFile.readLine());
   newList.addCourse(new Course(title, department, year));  
}
```

However, make sure that they always are in group of 3 lines, else you will encounter exception.

The best would be to have all 3 datas on the same line, separated by a delimiter so you could simply do :

```
String[] info;
while((nextLine = inFile.readLine()) != null)
{
    info  = nextLine.split(";");//; would be the delimiter
    title = info[0];
    department = info[1];
    year = Integer.parseInt(info[2]);
}
```

Comment: Thank-you! I think your delimiter method is something that I'm suppose to do. When would you use a `for` loop to assign values though?

Comment: @hello you are assigning values to 3 different variable. To assign them in a for-loop, you would need to validate them which is extra-process for nothing if you already know what they represent.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use Scanner for your task. But you need to specify some delimiter if Title or department has spaces.

```
try{
    String nextLine;
    String title = "";
    String department = "";
    int year;

    BufferedReader inFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputName));
    Scanner in = new Scanner(inFile);
    while((nextLine = inFile.readLine())!= null){

        title = in.next(); //if title has spaces, you need to use next(Pattern) instead or delimiter
        department = in.next(); //if department has spaces, you need to use next(Pattern) instead or delimiter
        year = in.nextInt();
        newList.addCourse(new Course(title, department, year));
    }

    inFile.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();  
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```